# Bringing the app into the foreground (maximized on top) from the minimize mode by time (Not by user interaction) automatically

Tags: c#, uwp

Required: Bringing the app into the foreground (maximized on top) from the minimize mode by time (Not by user interaction or confirms) automatically whether any app is running in the foreground or not.

Actual behavior:  App does not come into the foreground on top, just blinking (Orange) in the task bar.

Our requirement: Let’s understand the purpose, We have player that has one feature named screen saver like windows screen saver. Our app starts and play as user interacts with device in any way, our gets minimized, user continue to work in the devices, done and leave, then device gets idle for the sometime (No user interaction), then our app needs to be come into the foreground and play and so on.

I have tried many ways to get the app into the foreground but none of them worked, although it does try to get the app up but not bringing into the foreground, just blinks the app icon in the taskbar.

If we launch app into compact view by time, however app gets up but still does come on top of  all the apps running into the foreground.

When we launch the app from the debug (By visual studio), app comes into the foreground by time or code perfectly whether any app we are working on..

But when we launch app from startup (after installed - no debug), user interacts with device (like press or mouse move) app goes into minimize  mode as per logic and wait for a sometime without opening any app (be on desktop) provided, app comes into the foreground that's fine but if user opens any app while our app being in minimize mode then it would not come into the foreground just blinks app icon in the task bar.

We have also tried to launch the app into foreground by desktop extension bridge app but still same behavior found.

Comment: "*I have tried many ways to get the app into the foreground but none of them worked*" - maybe you should show what you have tried so people don't offer the same advice

Comment: I would recommend you read Raymond Chen's blog.    Things like being minimized then automatically going back to topmost fullscreen are sometimes blocked by Windows because it's that's a user invoked action, not a program invoked action (imagine if to programs did the same thing at the same time).

Comment: Thanks @Neil, could you please provide the specific Raymond Chen's blog that is related to it because I looked it up, can't find any relevant blog..

Comment: Hello @manigupta , the wake-up of the application should be handled by the user. UWP applications currently do not have this permission, that is, the application cannot wake up itself and return to the foreground.

Answer (score 1):

```cs
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
public static extern bool IsWindowVisible(IntPtr hWnd);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
public static extern bool IsIconic(IntPtr hWnd);

public delegate bool EnumedWindow(IntPtr handleWindow, ArrayList handles);

[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
public static extern bool EnumWindows(EnumedWindow lpEnumFunc, ArrayList lParam);

public static ArrayList GetAllWindows()
{
    ArrayList windowHandles = new ArrayList();
    EnumedWindow callBackPtr = GetWindowHandle;
    EnumWindows(callBackPtr, windowHandles);
    return windowHandles;
}

private static bool GetWindowHandle(IntPtr windowHandle, ArrayList windowHandles)
{            
    if (IsWindowVisible(windowHandle))
    {
        if (IsIconic(windowHandle))
        {
            ShowWindow(windowHandle, 3); //SW_MAXIMIZE
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```